# Month and year picker in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am looking for a month and year picker for my ionic app. currently I am using http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/ 
But I dont want the day picker in here . How to have only month and year to pick?

I am trying to get something like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to this component.........
https://github.com/petruisfan/ionic-monthpicker

Comment: You should see the ionic documentation.

Answer (score 1):

for ionic 6+ you can use this (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#month-and-year-selection)

```
<ion-datetime presentation="month-year"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the following question.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/YYYY" min="1994-03-14" max="2012-12-09"></ion-datetime>
```

displayFormat="MM/YYYY" you can use this for formating the Callander.

Comment: In the last version of Ionic (v. 6), [this component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) doesn't work like that anymore

Comment: Yes. this can be used only in ionic 4 to 5.